# How does cancelAnimationFrame deal with side-effects in the callback?

Tags: javascript, webgl

requestAnimationFrame takes a callback function which runs before the frame is displayed. Supposed this callback function has side-effects like:

```
function callback {
  ++GLOBAL_VAR_A;
  ++GLOBAL_VAR_B;
}
```

If I call cancelAnimationFrame on the request for that callback, will the callback be atomic? In other words, is the callback guaranteed to either execute completely or not execute at all? Or could the cancellation leave say `GLOBAL_VAR_A` incremented, but not `GLOBAL_VAR_B`?

Furthermore, if this callback is atomic, if I cancel the frame successfully, will the callback execute or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is mono-threaded, so this problem cannot show : either the callback was called or not when the cancelAF is called. If it was called, nothing is done. If it was not called, it won't get called later. Your question suggest that cancelAF would also cancel an ongoing callback, but the specification dooesn't say a word about that : MDN description is :

> window.cancelAnimationFrame
>
> Cancels an animation frame request previously scheduled through a
> call to window.requestAnimationFrame().

( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.cancelAnimationFrame ).

It is a 'request' which gets cancelled, not the callback.

Maybe to be a little clearer : if you call cancelAF after ++GLOBAL_VAR_A and before ++GLOBAL_VAR_B;, then it means the callback was allready called and the cancelAF does just nothing.

cancelAF has no return value, so you cannot tell you "cancel(led) the frame successfully"

Comment: Oh thanks! So the callback is definitely called because it must either be called before or after cancelAF and javascript is single threaded; the request is canceled, but not the callback, right? Thanks!